# Execution failed for task :processDebugResources [ react-native ]

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I present the following error when running react-native run-android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.042 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: I solved the same problem by installing "Android SDK Platform 23" and "Source for _Android 23" under Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)_

Comment: You need to provide more logs. The ProcessException is saying that executing aapt failed. There should be some errors above the stacktrace giving the reason for the failure.